# Downgrade samsung galaxy Note 3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I have samsung galaxy note 3(sm900)
Recently i updated my note 3 from kikat (4.4.2) to lollipop (5.0) via ota
Due to this my phone became very laggy and slow and often app crashes
I wish to downgrade my phone from lollipop to kitkat
How can i downgrade it

Comment: I tried searching on google but there was no specific answer to my query thats why i posted over here.

Answer (score 1):

Why go back?? 
Try a factory reset. I have a note 3 Exynos  on lollipop and it works really well. 
IMO the mobile is faster than it used to be on kitkat.

However if you want to downgrade, the download the latest version of kitkat and flash it using Odin.

Edit: Take the downgrade as a last resort since there is no sure way of knowing.. Sorry.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138168/discussion-on-answer-by-arjuna-downgrade-samsung-galaxy-note-3).